# python read text file to array and edit the array

Tags: python, arrays, join, addition

hello all im trying to read text file line by line and then store all the data into an array and i want to add text in the value of array such as

admin
administrator
adm
log
login

after got this lines i want to add (.php)
in the end of it

and this is my code

```
current_folder= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
current_list=str(current_folder)+"\pages.txt"

ins = open( current_list, "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append(line.rstrip())

for fahad in array:

    array+".php"
```

Comment: Do you want each value in the file or do you want the whole line to be an entry? For example `array = ['admin', 'administrator', 'adm', 'log', 'login']` or `array = ['admin administrator adm log login']`

Comment: In your last `for` lop there is an error. Replace `array` in the body with `fahad` and it should function the way you want it to

Comment: It looks like you're just talking about a list.  In Python "array" and "list" mean two different things.  In particular, an array is generally a homogeneous collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
try:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as ins: #Opens the file and closes it when Python is done with it
        array = []
        for line in ins:
            array.append(line.rstrip()) # appends each line of the file with trailing white space stripped

        for fahad in array:
            fahad += ".php" # for each item in the list 'array' it concatenates '.php' on to the end. The += operator is the same as fahad = fahad + '.php'
            print(fahad)

except FileNotFoundError: # this is part of a try/except block. If the file isn't found instead of throwing an error this will trigger. Right now nothing happens because of the pass statement but you can change that to print something if you like.
    pass
```

produces:

```
>>> fahad
'admin administrator adm log login.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
ins = open( "hello.txt", "r" )
array = []
rows = ins.read().split('\n') #or \r\n - it depends from your txt
for row in rows:
    array.append(row+".php")

ins.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work.

```
current_folder= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
current_list=str(current_folder)+"\pages.txt"

ins = open( current_list, "r" ).read().split()
array = []
for line in ins:
    array.append(line + ".php")
```